# Converter coluna para linha

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Este é o `select` de minha tabela, a *query* que estou usando segue na imagem abaixo:

[image: SS]

Ele traz o resultado normal, porém queria que ele trouxesse desta maneira:

| Id_Unica |   Pixel   | Polegada | Quantidade |
      18           1080p         15                2

Será que é possível pessoal?

Select atual:

```
SELECT id, id_unica, parametro, descricao, produto FROM inventario WHERE produto='Monitor' GROUP BY parametro ORDER BY parametro ASC;
```

Comment: Os nomes das colunas serão sempre estes?

Comment: Ola. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Prefira copiar os resultados da query inves de colocar uma imagem (torna mais facil a leitura). Confira [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como perguntar.

Comment: O nome das Colunas equivalem ao valor da variável parâmetro exceto a Id_unica, que será sempre o mesmo nome

Comment: Você parece querer "pivotar" a tabela. Marquei a pergunta como duplicada de outra cuja resposta explica o truque para fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT id + id_unica + parametro + descricao + produto 
FROM inventario 
WHERE produto='Monitor' 
GROUP BY parametro 
ORDER BY parametro ASC;
```

se o sinal do + não funcionar no MySQL, experimente o pipe "||" deve funcionar.

Comment: rcaratchuk, não funcionou deste jeito.

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa rápida na internet.
SELECT concat(id, '|' , id_unica , '|' , parametro , '|' , descricao , '|' , produto 
FROM inventario 
WHERE produto='Monitor' 
GROUP BY parametro 
ORDER BY parametro ASC;